# Why do I get a"previously declared in" error

Tags: php, wordpress

Jus tried to log in to my web admin and got this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare oceanwp_webfonts_enqueue() (previously declared in /home/customer/www/ozdistributorsusa.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ocean-extra/includes/compatibility/ocean.php:94) in /home/customer/www/ozdistributorsusa.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/inc/customizer/controls/typography/webfonts.php on line 128

I can't get acces to the actual site either, any suggestions?

Comment: This looks like a problem with your WP plugins and themes. They're defining the same function in two different files.

Answer (score 3):

To fix it I manually commented the following functions in `/wp-content/plugins/ocean-extra/includes/compatibility/ocean.php`:

- oceanwp_webfonts_enqueue()
- ocean_get_google_font_css()
- oceanwp_get_local_webfonts_data_dir()
- oceanwp_get_local_webfonts_css_data_dir()

It was a "bad" update, which is now already fixed in 2.0.4 (https://wordpress.org/plugins/ocean-extra/#developers)

After commenting you can update that plugin via the panel or alternatively you can manually update it by removing the folder `/wp-content/plugins/ocean-extra/` and uploading again the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I got access by changing the theme via in the Database (VIA PHPmyAdmin) for one of the ones that comes by default (like twentytwenty).

I installed a new theme but the whole thing seems unstable still. If nothing better comes up I'm starting a fresh install.

Answer (score -2):

oceanwp_webfonts_enqueue() function declare more than one. this function may be used in loop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).